# Detecting changes in SQL Azure, and publishing events

Tags: c#, .net, apache, azure-sql-database, event-sourcing

My company is currently using event sourcing pattern in our system. The system usually publishes events from applications, and then stores them in event store and at the same time update database (for query) via event handler. However, there are exceptional cases where database (which is SQL Azure) is updated without publishing events and updating the event store. To keep integrity of event store, I would like to detect changes (from the aforementioned cases) in SQL Azure and send events to event store for backfilling.

I checked there are couple of ways in .NET to achieve it using SQLTableDependency or websocket to detect SQL CDC (Change Data Capture). I found SQLTableDependency doesn't support SQL Azure.

I wonder if someone has experience in the similar technical challenge.

Comment: So why don't you want to use simple polling? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)

Comment: Yes, we currently have polling service to backfill events. I genuinely wanted to see how others handle this. I wonder if there is a way to stream it even using apache based tools. Thanks.

Comment: To be honest, I feel like you got a backdoor and now want to patch on every use of it instead of shutting the backdoor itself. It does not sound right.